# Random forest subscript out of bounds error?

Tags: r, random-forest

I am trying to create a random forest in R, using the following code:

```
forest <-
randomForest(Responder_7yr ~ CD4_num_log + CD8_num_log + anergy_CD8_num_log +
             anergy_CD4_num_log + part_exhaust_CD8_num_log + exhaustion_CD8_num_log + 
             exhaustion_CD4_num_log + senescence_CD8_num_log + 
             senescence_CD4_num_log + tcm_CD4negCD8pos_num_log + 
             nTreg_CD4posCD8neg_num_log + ln_cpep + A1C + Ins, 
             data=resp, na.action=na.omit, importance=TRUE)
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
Error in `[.default`(table(observed = y, predicted = out.class), levels(y),  : 
  subscript out of bounds
```

I've confirmed all predictors are in the proper format, and the outcome is in factor format. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Check your data to see the distribution in levels of your various predictors and outcomes. You may find that some of your predictor levels or outcome levels are very highly skewed, or some outcomes or predictor levels are very rare. I got that error when I was trying to predict a very rare outcome with a heavily tuned random forest, and so some of the predictor levels were not actually in the training data. Thus a factor level appears in the test data that the training data thinks is out of bounds.